# modify label's width in react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

Im drawing chart with my dynamic values and I need to know 2 things :

1/ modify the width of labels in x and y using the LineChart of react-native-chart-kit !!

2/ control the scale of my graph

If you know a proporties or options that can make this ;

```
 <LineChart
            data={this.state.data}
            width={Dimensions.get("window").width*0.9}
            height={400}
            //yAxisLabel={"DH"}
            chartConfig={chartConfig}
            bezier
            spacing={0.8}
            spacingInner={0.8}
            verticalLabelRotation={90}
            style={{
              marginTop:40,
              marginLeft:20,
              fontSize:1,
            }}
            />
const chartConfig = {
  backgroundColor: "#f5f3ed",
  backgroundGradientFrom: "#f5f3ed",
  backgroundGradientTo: "#f5f3ed",
  //decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(3, 2, 2, ${opacity})`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(3, 2, 2, ${opacity})`,
  barPercentage: 0.5,
  style: {
    borderRadius: 16
  },
  propsForDots: {
    r: "6",
    strokeWidth: "2",
    stroke: "#ffa726"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `propsForLabels` can be used to override styles of the labels, [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)
2. Scale of your graph is proportional to the extreme values of your data set. If you are looking to reduce the scale that means your data should be between a considerably smaller range.

Comment: HI, do you know if it is possible to have it always go from 0-100? Also, i need to make the labels for the Y-axis colored boxes, like red, yellow green. Do you know if that is possible too?